# error when sending email via XE2 delphi

Tags: delphi, email, delphi-xe2

I am using this simple code to send emails it works for most SMTP servers but for the Servers which using SMTP AUTH extension as defined in RFC 2554. it shows this error:

**ERROR: valid RCPT command must precede DATA**

here is the code :

```
    SMTP.Host := 'host.com';
  SMTP.Port := 25;
  SMTP.Username:= 'user@host.com';
  SMTP.Password:= 'pass';
  MailMessages.From.Address:='address@address.com';
  MailMessages.From.Name:= 'Ehsan';
  MailMessages.Subject :=  'Test';
  MailMessages.Body.Text := 'the body is going to test';
  MailMessages.ReceiptRecipient.Address := 'ehsan.hesam13@gmail.com';

  try
    try
     SMTP.Connect;
     SMTP.Authenticate;
     SMTP.Send(MailMessages);
    except on E:Exception do
      StatusMemo.Lines.Insert(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

how can i solve this problem in XE2?
thankx

Comment: Is this actual code? I see syntax errors within your `try..except` block. And what kind of objects are `SMTP` and `MailMessages`?

Comment: Do you add a recipient somewhere?

Comment: i corrected the real code . also the SMTP is TIdSMTP and MailMessages is TIdMessage. this code works for the normal SMTP servers but for the server s which use SMTP AUTH it shows following error : ERROR: valid RCPT command must precede DATA it means we should auth before send email and i don't know how to auth before sending :D in XE2 delphi

Comment: Let me ask again. Do you add a recipient? RCPT isn't about authentication, it is about who is the recipient of your e-mail. I wouldn't know why an e-mail is accepted without a recipient when you don't authenticate, but anyway it seems that your e-mail is incomplete without a recipient. `ReceiptRecipient` is not the recipient. It is the recipient of a read-notification (a receipt), so it will usually be the sender rather than the recipient.

Comment: Okay, the comment above may not be completely correct. I read a bit, and it could be that this error is given when your authentication isn't accepted. This could happen because of incorrrect credentials, but also because of your IP being blacklisted (if you've been experimenting a lot, that might happen). You can check that [here](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx). I also find lots of other possibilities that could cause it when searching for your error message, so maybe the problem isn't in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are filling in the `TIdMessage.Recipients`, `TIdMessage.CCList`, or `TIdMessage.BCCList` properties.  Those are the properties where `TIdSMTP` gets the addresses for its SMTP `RCPT TO` commands.  You cannot send an email without specify the recipient(s) for it.  You are only filling in the `TIdMessage.ReceiptRecipient` property, which is only meant for specifying the return address that recipients send read receipts to, if recipients support read recipients.

Also, you do not need to call `Authenticate()` manually.  `Send()` calls it internally for you when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all , I have filled the `Recipients.EMailAddresses` and it worked :D
 here is the correct code :

```
  SMTP.Host := 'host.com';
  SMTP.Port := 25;
  SMTP.Username:= 'user@host.com';
  SMTP.Password:= 'pass';
  MailMessages.From.Address:='address@address.com';
  MailMessages.From.Name:= 'Ehsan';
  MailMessages.Subject :=  'Test';
  MailMessages.Body.Text := 'the body is going to test';
  MailMessages.Recipients.EMailAddresses:='ehsan.hesam13@gmail.com';

  try
    try
     SMTP.Connect;
     SMTP.Authenticate;
     SMTP.Send(MailMessages);
    except on E:Exception do
      StatusMemo.Lines.Insert(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Thank you again.